# Setting the default zoom for the preview window in Gummi (LaTeX editor)

Tags: latex, editor

I have a question about a (somewhat) old LaTeX editor for linux called Gummi, found [here](https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi).

In Gummi, you have a live preview of the LaTeX document you are editing. This preview has a zoom level, the default being 100%. You can change it to a different level but it reverts to default if you switch documents. Does anyone know how to change the default level or how to stop it from reverting to the default between documents?

In theory I could edit the source code to make this change since it is an open source project but I am too naive to complete this task, maybe someone can direct me on what to do (but it's probably nontrivial...)?

Comment: Hi!! Why don't you contact the developer through the [**GitHub** page](https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi)? :)